# Android Studio - processDebugResources failed

Tags: android, gradle

So I'm trying to build my project in Android Studio, but each time the project has been loaded or been executed, I get the following error. I have no clue how to fix this ...

```
Execution failed for task ':oefening1:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
C:\Users\Jorre\AppData\Local\Android\android-studio1\sdk\build-tools\android-        4.4.2\aapt.exe package -f --no-crunch -I C:\Users\Jorre\AppData\Local\Android\android-studio1\sdk\platforms\android-19\android.jar -M C:\Users\Jorre\Desktop\Android\Oefening\oefening1\build\manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml -S C:\Users\Jorre\Desktop\Android\Oefening\oefening1\build\res\all\debug -A C:\Users\Jorre\Desktop\Android\Oefening\oefening1\build\assets\debug -m -J C:\Users\Jorre\Desktop\Android\Oefening\oefening1\build\source\r\debug -F C:\Users\Jorre\Desktop\Android\Oefening\oefening1\build\libs\oefening1-debug.ap_ --debug-mode --custom-package be.verstraetejordy.oefening1
Error Code:    -1073741819
```

This is my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar', '*.aar'])
}
```

anyone got a solution for me? :/ Keep in mind that I'm a beginner and don't know much about Android Studio or Gradle ..

Comment: Did you make sure your AndroidManifest.xml is correct?  I.e. it has the correct package name and android name suffixes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, honestly: the way I fixed it was by reinstalling Android Studio after doing a System Recovery.
My virus scanner was interrupting the gradle.build, causing it to fail every time.

So I did a System Recovery to the point where I didn't install a lot of stuff, reinstalled Android Studio again and it worked perfectly.

So there's no exact cause to this, just some shitty stuff with virus scanners.

If any on you still have this, I think it's due to a lot of different reasons.
Good luck fixing yours!

Answer (score 18):

If this is happenning to you after switching to `compileSdkVersion 21` make sure you use `buildToolsVersion "21.0.2"` (or later), not `"21.0.1"`.

Comment: This was a horribly obscure error and if I didn't read this post it would have taken me forever to find. thanks man.

Answer (score 11):

You're hitting bug https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=42752 which is that the AAPT compiler in the Android build process sometimes crashes when it receives certain kinds of bad input. Based on that bug report and also https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61308 it's usually caused by a `@string` reference in a **menu.xml** file to a string that doesn't exist. Give it a careful look and see if you can find one that's wrong.

Comment: I found my problem in menu.xml.  I was taking out v7 support lib, but was still referencing it.  The debug msg is pretty much useless, thanks Scott for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: In my case, also same menu problem, Android Studio creates a sample menu file in `res/menu` folder automatically.

Comment: In my case, I was using appcompat themes and not using app:showAsAction attributes for menu items.

Comment: in my case it was due to special characters in my strins.xml file.   for example ( ' and " )

Comment: Thanks, in my case I was missing an icon in the `res` folder, once I added it, all was well

Answer (score 7):

> As you may have already found, this error can be visible due to many reasons. Hence you need to find actual reason behind the error.

Navigate to android folder and issue below command;

```
gradlew.bat --info clean build
```

OR

```
./gradlew --info clean build
```

This will list the actual issue, rectify that and redo the build.

Hope this is helpful!

Comment: This is the best solution because you see the actual error. The answer could also state that the gradlew.bat exist in every android app solution folder, e.g. the place that open when you right-click App and select "Show in Explorer".

Successfully started process 'command 'C:\Users\fimatronn\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\23.0
.3\aapt.exe''
D:\VSProjects\Android\HelgaClient\app\build\intermediates\assets\debug\my erroneus filesname: error: In
valid filename.  Unable to add.
:app:processDebugResources FAILED

Comment: Oh my. I would have never figured this out. Apparently there was already an archived file in my application, but only after using your command I managed to figure that out. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

This problem seems to be pretty generic. My solution was to rebuild the project (Build -> Rebuild) since Android Studio hadn't automatically detected a resource I created before the problem occurred.

Comment: in my case, just doing the Rebuild itself worked! but your post was good enough to provide the hint

Answer (score 3):

In my case I was using `app:showAsAction` instead of `android:showAsAction` after removing v4 and v7 compatibility libraries in my `menu/*.xml` file. Here is a sample diff:

```
     <item android:id="@+id/action_calendar"
         android:title="Calendar"
         android:orderInCategory="100"
         android:icon="@drawable/calendar"
-        app:showAsAction="never" />
+        android:showAsAction="never" />
```

This solved my issue.

Comment: This also fixed my issue, but in the opposite direction. Adding xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" to the <menu /> element and app:showAsAction instead of android:showAsAction on the <item /> elements got my build working again in Android Studio 0.8.1/Gradle plugin 0.12.

Answer (score 2):

Updating your `buildToolsVersion` in your app's `build.gradle` should fix your problem. Switching from `'21.0.0' to '21.0.2'` solved that problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

Run your gradle build with `--debug` option and just check the error that is reported there.

To change the gradle options in Android studio (1.3), go to `file->settings->Build,Execution,Deployment->compiler` and add `--debug` in the command-line options field.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by uninstall and reinstall the latest version of Android SDK Tools and Android SDK Platform-tools.

1) Open Android Studio
2) Go to Tools-> Android -> SDK Manager
3) choose "Launch Standalone SDK Manager 
4) deselect all 
5) select the latest Android SDK Tools and Android SDK Platform-tools.
6) click on "delete 2 packages"
7) Now you need to reinstall the packages you just uninstalled. Select the latest Android SDK Tools and Android SDK Platform-tools.
8) click on "Install 2 packages"

If you have other error on build number just return on Tools-> Android -> SDK Manager
choose "Launch Standalone SDK Manager
install the build you have the error on it. Example: if you receive an error on build 23.0.3 just install Android SDK Buid-tools 23.0.3
After you can update it to the latest build

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was solved by removing references in AndroidManifest.xml to a theme that I had removed from themes.xml in res/values.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had a `.jar` dependency in `app/src/main/assets` after the import of my Eclipse project into Android Studio. I did the following:

- I created a folder `app/libs`;
- Moved the `.jar` into that folder;
- Removed the `app/src/main/assets` folder (it was now empty);
- Updated `app/build.gradle` by including the following at the bottom of the file:

  dependencies {
      compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  }

Answer (score 0):

Use the latest version of Android Studio build tools.

compileSdkVersion 23
 buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

Comment: Could you please provide more information on how your proposed solution helps?

Comment: @ Wtower: In my case after updating android studio ,i faced this problem, so i changed the build version into latest, then remove the caches by using menu  Files-> Invalidated Caches / Restart. for me its working. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the package name in app ***build.gradle*** file was changed by mistake:

```
applicationId "com.mypackagename"
```