# Android studio: Error Code: -1073741819 - Using ABS, ViewPagerIndicator,FacebookSDK and cannot build project

Tags: compiler-errors, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

So here is the run down: I am importing an existing project from Eclipse into Android Studio by hand. I keep getting this error which prevents me from building my project and my R file is also not generated:

**The error ( Full stacktrace is at the end of this post )**

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
```

> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
>           C:\android-sdk\build-tools\19.0.1\aapt.exe package -f --no-crunch -I C:\android-sdk\platforms\android-19\android.jar -M C:\Users\MyUserName\workspace
>   Eclipse\CrazyApp\app\build\manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml -S C:\Users\MyUserName\workspaceEclipse\CrazyApp\app\build\res\all\debug -A C:\Users\MyUserName\workspaceE
>   clipse\CrazyApp\app\build\assets\debug -m -J C:\Users\MyUserName\workspaceEclipse\CrazyApp\app\build\source\r\debug -F C:\Users\MyUserName\workspaceEclipse\CrazyApp\app\bui
>   ld\libs\app-debug.ap_ --debug-mode --custom-package com.CrazyApp --output-text-symbols C:\Users\MyUserName\workspaceEclipse\CrazyApp\app\build\symbols\debug
>   **Error Code:
>           -1073741819**

**my gradle files and stuff:**
I have an android project with ActionBarSherlock and ViewPagerIndicator, along with the Facebook SDK. I am referencing the ViewPagerIndicator and Facebook libraries externally like so:

[image: hierarchy]

Then I am using this **app/gradle.build** file to install the Actionbarsherlock and compile the libraries:

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 17
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.0.30'
    compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
    compile project(':libraries:facebook')
    compile project(':libraries:ViewPagerIndicator')
}
```

[image]

**This is my settings.gradle file:**

```
include ':app', ':libraries:facebook', ':libraries:ViewPagerIndicator'
```

**This is my libraries' gradle files:**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.7.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android-library'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18+'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 17
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
        }
    }
}
```

**Error after executing : gradlew --stacktrace --info**

```
.....more skipped tasks before that....
Skipping task ':app:processDebugManifest' as it is up-to-date (took 0.008 secs).
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE  
:app:processDebugManifest (Thread[main,5,main]) completed. Took 0.024 secs.
:app:processDebugResources (Thread[main,5,main]) started.
:app:processDebugResources             
Executing task ':app:processDebugResources' (up-to-date check took 0.265 secs) due to:
  No history is available.             
All input files are considered out-of-date for incremental task ':app:processDebugResources'.
command: C:\android-sdk\build-tools\19.0.1\aapt.exe package -f --no-crunch -I C:\android-sdk\platforms\android-19\android.jar -M C:\Users\MyUserName\workspac
eEclipse\CrazyApp\app\build\manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml -S C:\Users\MyUserName\workspaceEclipse\CrazyApp\app\build\res\all\debug -A C:\Users\MyUserName\workspace
Eclipse\CrazyApp\app\build\assets\debug -m -J C:\Users\MyUserName\workspaceEclipse\CrazyApp\app\build\source\r\debug -F C:\Users\MyUserName\workspaceEclipse\CrazyApp\app\bu
ild\libs\app-debug.ap_ --debug-mode --custom-package com.CrazyApp --output-text-symbols C:\Users\MyUserName\workspaceEclipse\CrazyApp\app\build\symbols\debug
:app:processDebugResources FAILED      
:app:processDebugResources (Thread[main,5,main]) completed. Took 3.161 secs.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
        C:\android-sdk\build-tools\19.0.1\aapt.exe package -f --no-crunch -I C:\android-sdk\platforms\android-19\android.jar -M C:\Users\MyUserName\workspace
Eclipse\CrazyApp\app\build\manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml -S C:\Users\MyUserName\workspaceEclipse\CrazyApp\app\build\res\all\debug -A C:\Users\MyUserName\workspaceE
clipse\CrazyApp\app\build\assets\debug -m -J C:\Users\MyUserName\workspaceEclipse\CrazyApp\app\build\source\r\debug -F C:\Users\MyUserName\workspaceEclipse\CrazyApp\app\bui
ld\libs\app-debug.ap_ --debug-mode --custom-package com.CrazyApp --output-text-symbols C:\Users\MyUserName\workspaceEclipse\CrazyApp\app\build\symbols\debug
Error Code:
        -1073741819


* Try:    
Run with --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:42)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:286)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.executeTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:63)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:51)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$1.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:33)
        at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheAccess.java:198)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheAccess.java:266)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.longRunningOperation(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:135)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.j
ava:93)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:31)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:86)
        at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:29)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:67)
        at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:166)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:113)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:81)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:64)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:24)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:50)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:171)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:201)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:174)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:170)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:139)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:46)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:50)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:32)
        at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:33)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:130)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:48)
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException: com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
        C:\android-sdk\build-tools\19.0.1\aapt.exe package -f --no-crunch -I C:\android-sdk\platforms\android-19\android.jar -M C:\Users\MyUserName\workspace
Eclipse\CrazyApp\app\build\manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml -S C:\Users\MyUserName\workspaceEclipse\CrazyApp\app\build\res\all\debug -A C:\Users\MyUserName\workspaceE
clipse\CrazyApp\app\build\assets\debug -m -J C:\Users\MyUserName\workspaceEclipse\CrazyApp\app\build\source\r\debug -F C:\Users\MyUserName\workspaceEclipse\CrazyApp\app\bui
ld\libs\app-debug.ap_ --debug-mode --custom-package com.CrazyApp --output-text-symbols C:\Users\MyUserName\workspaceEclipse\CrazyApp\app\build\symbols\debug
Error Code:
        -1073741819

        at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:39)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:70)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.
java:236)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:
212)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.ja
va:223)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:
201)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:530)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:513)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
        ... 52 more
Caused by: com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
        C:\android-sdk\build-tools\19.0.1\aapt.exe package -f --no-crunch -I C:\android-sdk\platforms\android-19\android.jar -M C:\Users\MyUserName\workspace
Eclipse\CrazyApp\app\build\manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml -S C:\Users\MyUserName\workspaceEclipse\CrazyApp\app\build\res\all\debug -A C:\Users\MyUserName\workspaceE
clipse\CrazyApp\app\build\assets\debug -m -J C:\Users\MyUserName\workspaceEclipse\CrazyApp\app\build\source\r\debug -F C:\Users\MyUserName\workspaceEclipse\CrazyApp\app\bui
ld\libs\app-debug.ap_ --debug-mode --custom-package com.CrazyApp --output-text-symbols C:\Users\MyUserName\workspaceEclipse\CrazyApp\app\build\symbols\debug
Error Code:
        -1073741819

        at com.android.ide.common.internal.CommandLineRunner.runCmdLine(CommandLineRunner.java:98)
        at com.android.ide.common.internal.CommandLineRunner.runCmdLine(CommandLineRunner.java:69)
        at com.android.builder.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:728)
        at com.android.builder.AndroidBuilder$processResources.call(Unknown Source)
        at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessAndroidResources.doFullTaskAction(ProcessAndroidResources.groovy:95)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.groovy:64)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:63)
        ... 60 more


BUILD FAILED

Total time: 18.285 secs
Stopped 0 Gradle compiler daemon(s).
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21645961/android-studio-processdebugresources-failed/21648362#21648362

Comment: I tried looking everywhere for such an error in my xml's and there was nothing wrong. Is there a way to tell android studio to do an extensive search to show where the error is?

Comment: If it's not showing it to you in syntax highlighting, I'm not sure what else you could do to have it help you out. in that SO question it links to a bug where there was a report of the same failure in a non-menu resource, so it could be something else that's wrong. If you've changed something recently to cause this to happen, you should definitely look through your recent history to see what changed.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same error (at least according to error code):

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   :app:processSandboxAllChecksOffDebugResources'.
>   com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run
>   command: ....... ....... .......
>   android\app\build\intermediates\symbols\sandboxAllChecksOff\debug
>   Error Code:   -1073741819

The problem was due to an extra file in my resource folder (res/drawable-xxhdpi). I occasionally put zip file there.

To fix the problem I had to:

1. Remove invalid file (zip file in my case, can be something different in yours)
2. Clean project