# Android - IntelliJ make fails with the "Error:android-apt-compiler .... execution failed with exit code -1073741819"

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

I know this question has been asked prior to this in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23912739/android-studio-on-make-project-gives-error-execution-failed-with-exit-code-10) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21645961/android-studio-processdebugresources-failed)
but I can't seem to find a solution to this issue.

I checked every single thing from 
Checking all the resource files, manually running through the strings.xml to even updating IntelliJ Idea (I am using IntelliJ 13) not the Android studio, but unfortunately nothing seems to work.

I am using app-compact in my project to show the ActionBar in Android Versions prior to Honeycomb.'

```
> Error:android-apt-compiler: Command
> "D:\AndroidSDK\build-tools\19.0.2\aapt.exe package -m
> --auto-add-overlay --extra-packages android.support.v7.appcompat --output-text-symbols C:\Users\Mushtaq\.IntelliJIdea13\system\compile-server\hac_89cbbfa5\android\intermediate_artifacts\HAC\r_txt
> -J C:\Users\Mushtaq\.IntelliJIdea13\system\compile-server\_temp_\android_apt_output5484624330942511062tmp
> -M C:\Users\Mushtaq\Desktop\HAC\AndroidManifest.xml -S C:\Users\Mushtaq\Desktop\HAC\res -S
> C:\Users\Mushtaq\Desktop\HAC\library\appcompat_v7\res -I
> D:\AndroidSDK\platforms\android-19\android.jar" execution failed with
> exit code -1073741819
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the issue, I was had a messed up **drawable xml** which had a truncated xml namespace, which in turn did not let the R class to generate.

The weird part is it was not showing up in any of the IDE's, it was failing silently and had to go through each and every file to come up with Issue. Not cool Android Lint/IDE, wasted almost a day.

If your `R`class does not generate it is ALWAYS and I mean ALWAYS the issue is with a resource file, do not look/think for one second that the issue is at some place else.Lesson learnt the hard way.

**Edit :**

I don't understand why the error message thrown by the IDE has to be so cryptic.