# After adding ressource "processDebugResources failed"

Tags: android, gradle, resources

Gradle say that he can't build correctly because of an unknown error, But i haven't changed anything on particular, so why is this happenning ?

I have already saw answer that say that you have to change your gradle.build file versions as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21645961/android-studio-processdebugresources-failed), to install 32 bit dependecys, or to `./gradlew clean build`

What i've done ?

Answer is below.

Comment: Run `gradle clean build --stacktrace` and give us the result.  It may show some insite

Comment: Please post logcat error !

Comment: This is a Q&A post, answer is below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is very simple but if you don't consider it, you'll be searching eternally for nothing.

In fact, sometime this error happen when you change file names and extension.

Well let's say that I had a file called "test.jpg", to do different test, I replaced it by a "test.png".

This cause gradle going crazy because you changed the file's extension but the name didn't.

I didn't found any topic talking about this kind of error so I post this here, hope this can help someone.