# Error:resource directory\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug' does not exist

Tags: android

I facing this error when i import this project.

please give me tips.how can i solve this issue

My android Studio Version Is : 2.3.3

## -Error1 : Error:resource directory\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug' does not exist

## -Error2 : Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

Thank You

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio - processDebugResources failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21645961/android-studio-processdebugresources-failed)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the build directory is an auto generated directory:

***1. remove it***

***2. clean the project***

and

***3. rebuild***